# A Rails Engine that overrides models from another engine isn't passing zeitwerk checks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6

I am creating two engines. [Engine Two](https://github.com/ActiveTarget/ActiveAttack) builds on [Engine One](https://github.com/ActiveTarget/ActiveAttack). I am using both of these Engines in [an application](https://github.com/ActiveTarget/ActiveIntel) I'm building. I used the `class_eval` Engine [overriding technique](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#overriding-models-and-controllers) mentioned in the rails guide.

```rb
# app/models/active_stix/tool_override.rb
ActiveStix::Tool.class_eval do
# Model override code here
end
```

The override is required from lib/engine_name/engine.rb as follows

```rb
    initializer "active_attack.update_stix" do |app|
      engine_root = File.expand_path("../../..", __FILE__)
      Dir.glob(engine_root + "/app/overrides/**/*_override*.rb").each do |c|
        require_dependency(c)
      end
    end
```

Everything works as expected in development, but when I run `rails zeitwerk:check` or try to deploy the application to Heroku, I get the following error

> expected file ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/active_attack-0.1.14/app/overrides/models/active_stix/tool_override.rb to define constant Models::ActiveStix::ToolOverride

This seems to be related to [Rails issue 36100](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/36100), but that issue seems to describe how the main Rails app can override Engine models. It doesn't seem to work for one Engine overriding another Engine's models.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in [Github Issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/38935)

`Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore(absolute/path/to/app/overrides)` ignores the overrides directory.

`config.autoloader = :classic` uses previous Rails autoloader instead of zeitwerk.